# Android error with TextView.OnEditorActionListener()

Tags: android-studio

How can I fix this error? The method does not override the method from its supeprclass and the error appears in the [TextView.OnEditorActionListener] anonymous class.

This error always shows @overrride error and error in  TextView.OnEditorActionListener() - [and there is the same error in editoraction].

```
private EditText mUserName;
private EditText mPassword;
private Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mlogin_page);

    mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameet);
    mUserName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override

    public boolean onEditiraction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent)
        {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                mPassword.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }

    });



    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordet);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinbtn);
```

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you [edit] your question to provide a meaningful title. StackOverflow is not a forum and the only thing that will help you get an answer is to be as more clear and specific about your problem as you can get.

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo but "onEditiraction" isn't an overridable method in  TextView.OnEditorActionListener.